# Asking for player name and age using OOP

Tags: object-oriented, pygame

I have a text adventure game and I need to use OOP so I've chosen to use it when getting the player's name and age. I need to keep the OOP; but was wondering if there are any ways to clean up the code or simplify it while still getting the overall output.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_name()
        self.verify_age()

    def get_name(self):
        print("If you are ready lets begin!")
        while True:
            print("What is your name?")
            name = input(":> ")
            if not name.istitle():
                print("Please enter a name starting with a capital letter; try again.")
            else:
                self.name = name
                print("Hello " + name + " prepare for battle.")
                break

    def verify_age(self):
        while True:
            print("Before we begin please verify your age. \nWhat is your age?")
            age = input(":> ")
            try:
                if 8 < int(age) <= 110:
                    self.age = age
                    break
                elif int(age) <= 8:
                    print("You are not old enough to play the game! Try again.")
                else:
                    print("You can't be that old, come on! Try again.")
            except:
                print("That is not a valid number! Try again.")
```

Comment: This is just the class. How will you be actually using this in your game?

Answer (score 1):

The methods in this class are not really Player methods. They are a combination of game flow, user input and value verification methods.   I'd organize it more like this.

```
class Game:
  def __init__(self):
    io.show("If ready, let's begin")
    name = self.get_valid_name()
    age = self.get_valid_age()
    self.player = Player(name, age)
    io.show("Hello {}, prepare for battle".format(self.player.get_name()))
```

The `Game` object owns the flow of control.  The I/O is encapsulated in an object which can be a simple stdio wrapper for now, but may eventually include non-blocking input or html output or whatever - don't tie the game logic to the display method.  The `Player` object contains player state.

The `get_valid_x` methods can basically be what you have now. If you are using that pattern over and over, you could get fancy and write a parameterized validator:

```
def get_valid_input(prompt, validation_func):
  while True:
    input = io.prompt(prompt)
    guidance = validation_func(input)
    if not guidance:
      return input
    io.show(guidance)

def validate_name(str):
  if not str.istitle():
    return "Please enter name beginning with capital Letter" 
  return None

 ...
 
 name = get_valid_input("What is your name?", validate_name)
```